cygwin1.dll version 3.5.* failing on Windows 10 Enterprise. Need to revert to cygwin1.dll v3.4
Updating Cygwin on Windows 10 Enterprise generates errors for all applications dependent on cygwin1.dll versions 3.5.*.
During update errors appear:
"The code execution cannot proceed because cygwin1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem".
"Postinstall script errors These do not necessarily mean that affected packages will fail to function properly, but please check /var/log/setup.log.full and report any problems" Setup.log postings listed below.
It appears that all instances of cygwin1.dll version 3.5.* have been broken.
Manually replacing cygwin1.dll v3.5 with previous v3.4 completes installation successfully.
After v3.4 install completes; base applications seem to function: (cygwin terminal, vim, less, python)
Most other applications started within a cygwin terminal die/crash/halt silently.
(emacs-w32, ssh, sftp)
Is there a graceful means of reverting to the version 3.4 applications which functioned before the attempted update?
Is there a workaround for the malfunctioning cygwin1.dll v3.5 family?
Errors noted in /var/log/setup.log:
2024/07/03 12:08:49 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:49 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_fontconfig_dtd.dash"
2024/07/03 12:08:49 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:49 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_glib2.0.sh"
2024/07/03 12:08:49 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:49 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_hicolor-icon-theme.sh"
2024/07/03 12:08:50 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:50 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db-update-ndex.dash"
2024/07/03 12:08:50 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:50 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_octave_finish.dash"
2024/07/03 12:08:50 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:50 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_shared-mime-info.sh"
2024/07/03 12:08:51 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741515
2024/07/03 12:08:51 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_texlive_finish.dash"
Using Cygwin setup-x86_64.exe version 2.932.
Platform:
OS Name           Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise,
Version      10.0.19045 Build 19045,
Manufacturer           Microsoft Corporation,
System Manufacturer  LENOVO,
System Model  20YQ003YUS,
System Type     x64-based PC
Cygwin Update Download sites: http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu or https://mirror.clarkson.edu
I've been using Cygwin software for years. It's a reliable alternative to the Windows mindset. Cygwin scripts has saved countless hours of manual effort. It has never failed an installation or update before.
I'd really appreciate some assistance.
Thanks in Advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To Clarify: The Cygwin DLL cygwin1.dll version 3.5 first released in January 2024 is not functioning on Windows 10 Enterprise. Reversion to an earlier x64 release is required.

The question is bipartite: 1. How to repair DLL v3.5 and 2. How to revert to DLL 3.4.

The Cygwin1.dll v3.5 fails on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045. Diagnoses will likely require a on-premises source build. This has not been completed.

Reversion to Cygwin1.dll v3.4 is outlined on http://www.cygwin.com under the title "Q: How can I install the last Cygwin version for an old, unsupported Windows?" A solutional DOS command line expression is:


setup-x86_64.exe --allow-unsupported-windows --no-verify --site http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/64bit/2024/01/30/231215
Carefully enter the URL listed to avoid an "Unable to get setup from <www.cygwin.com>" failure.
During installation the dialog "Choose A Download Site" appears. Verify the dialog URL matches the command line URL; "http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org". Otherwise the installation will fail: "The code execution cannot proceed because cygwin1.dll was not found".
